# Can avr-gcc use sys/socket.h?

Tags: c, sockets, avr-gcc

I have a program that compiles with no problems on my Raspberry Pi using `gcc` that includes the statement:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

My intent for this project, though, is to use it on an Arduino. I have installed avr-gcc, avr-LibC, and avrdude, but when I try to compile using:

```
avr-gcc Project.c -o Project
```

I receive the error message:

```
fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
```

I thought `socket.h` was part of the C standard library. Is it possible to install this library for use by avr-gcc, or is there a way I can point to this library's directory (I have been unable to find it myself in the usual folders, but GCC seems to be able to find it)?

Comment: Without an operating system, it's meaningless to have `socket.h` `I thought socket.h was part of the C standard library` - `sys/socket.h` is part of [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html). `to this library's directory` but even if you "point" it, there is no operating system to service the syscalls. You would have to write them yourself.

Comment: See http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_11.html

Comment: Many standard library features are not available in uCs. Forget also about malloc & friends.

Comment: @MiCo useless comment considering 2k RAM 8bit uC

Answer (score 3):

> Can avr-gcc use sys/socket.h?

No. It cannot. That's not a limitation of the compiler though. It's a limitation of the system your code needs to be run on.

The `sys/*.h` headers are not part of the C standard library. They are only available on POSIX compliant operating systems, and expose C functions to interact with the OS. The `sys/socket.h` header provides functions to communicate with the operating system to create, manipulate and interact with sockets.

Since sockets are a feature provided by the operating system, and you are compiling code that runs bare-metal on an Arduino microcontroller, which has *no operating system* running on top, the whole purpose of the `sys/socket.h` header is nullified.

This applies to any other kind of header or library function that interacts with the operating system, such as `unistd.h`, `fcntl.h`, `pthread.h` etc. In fact, `avr-libc`, the Standard C library for AVR-GCC, does not provide such headers.

You will need to look at [the `avr-libc` documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html) to find out more about the headers and functions that are provided and their usage.